# How to disable remote certificate validation using .NET SSLStreams

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In .NET  SSLStream class, while invoking "AuthenticateAsClient" method, it is mandatory to pass the "targetHost", based on which the validation of remote certificates takes place.

If targetHost is set to '*' then validation of remote certificates doesn't take place as stated in the msdn [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ca67aa4-8c65-43d7-8dca-a1e251e044f1/net-sslstream-authenticateasclient-what-is-targethost?forum=netfxbcl)

Now is there as way that we set the 'targetHost' to a valid value and still want to disable the validation of remote certificate.

Comment: From the server side there is a code sample in the class documentation. Check [SSLSTream class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Thank you. But this is on the client side hence was using AuthenticateAsClient

Comment: The `AuthenticateAsClient` has an [AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions) overload](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream_AuthenticateAsClient_System_Net_Security_SslClientAuthenticationOptions_). Looking at the [SslClientAuthenticationOptions documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslclientauthenticationoptions?view=net-5.0) there is an `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` that you could use to ignore remote wrong/invalid certificates.

Comment: @Cleptus Thanks for your advice sir and could you pls post it as the answer to end this ticket?

Comment: @TinyWang, I was far from a computer just added an answer, sorry for the delay and... Happy coding ;-).

Comment: @Cleptus Yeah, happy coding : D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a certificate validation callback so you can decide when to accept or ignore the remote certificate, in you use case you want to ignore the remote certificate and accept it regardless of the errors.

With the `SSLStream` there are two ways to achieve it:

1. Use the [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Boolean_System_Net_Security_RemoteCertificateValidationCallback_) that has the `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` argument. You have a code sample in [the official documentation of the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-5.0#examples)
2. Use the [AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions) overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream_AuthenticateAsClient_System_Net_Security_SslClientAuthenticationOptions_) that has a `SslClientAuthenticationOptions` argument with an `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` property that you could use to ignore remote wrong/invalid certificates.

The code of the custom callback function would be similar to this one:

```cs
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
      object sender,
      X509Certificate certificate,
      X509Chain chain,
      SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   // We want to ignore remote certificate errors
   // Warning: In a normal scenario we would check the sslPolicyErrors argument instead.
   return true;
}
```